# Remove trailing comma from array results using EJS in Node express?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have an array stored in my MongoDB database.

```
"tags": [
        "Engineer",
        "Programmer"
 ]
```

But whenever I want to display the results on the frontend using EJS framework the results always come with a trailing comma: `Engineer, Programmer`.

Meanwhile, what I really wanted to have is `Engineer Programmer` without the comma.

I want to link each entity. For example:
`<a href="/programmer"> Programmer </a> <a href="/Engineer"> Engineer </a>`.

So this is the code I have so far:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) { %>

      <a href="tags/"> <%= tags[i] %> </a> 
<%}%>
```

I'd appreciate any pointer to remove the comma.

Thanks!

Comment: there's no reason for a comma in the code you provided. are you sure it's not a part of  the value? Try setting tags  var tags = ["Engineer","Programmer"]; right in the template and see the comma gone.

Comment: Comma is still there.

Comment: more details are required then to be able to answer this. this is probably not your whole template. the code that calls this template affects the result, it could shed some light as well.

Comment: @IgorR please check this more elaborate explanation to answer the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666618/how-to-display-array-in-frontend-using-ejs-in-mongodb-node-js