# How to display array in frontend using EJS in Mongodb Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm currently building an app where I need to save an array of tags into MongoDB using express js in Node Js.

Here is the method I used for saving my tags as an array into MongoDB.

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('meme'), function (req, res) {
    if (req.file) {

//upload to cloudinary. 
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {use_filename: true, folder: 'test'},
    function(error, result) {
//get the image name
var filePath = req.file.originalname; 

//instantiate the meme schema
var newMeme = new meme(); 

newMeme.imgs = filePath; 

//get the caption form field value 
newMeme.caption = req.body.caption;  

//get the tags value from the form field. 

newMeme.tags = req.body.tags.replace(/\s/g,'').split(',');

//cloudinary url
newMeme.url = result.url

//encrypt the filepath 
newMeme.memeid = hash.unique(filePath); 


newMeme.save(function(err){

 if (err) throw err; 

}); 

res.cookie('filename',newMeme.url);

//return res.send('sucessfully uploaded');

res.redirect('meme/'+newMeme.memeid);

}); 

}else{
//throw error message
return res.send('failed to upload'); 

}

})
```

My Mongoose schema looks like this:

```
var memeSchema = mongoose.Schema ({

imgs: String,       
id: Number,
memeid: String, 
favorites: Number,
url: String,  
caption: String, 
username: String,
tags: [],  
uploadDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

After saving, my DB looks something like this:

```
 "tags": [
        "Suprised",
        "Laughing"
    ],
```

Now when I want to display the tags, I'm having problem rendering the results properly.

My desired result is to display them with link wrap around each result, not with comma.

For example: `<a href="/tags/suprised"> Surprised </a> <a href="/tags/Laughing"> Surprised </a>`

This is the result I'm getting: `<a href="/tags/Suprised,Laughing"> Surprised, Laughing </a>`

I want them to be separate.

This is my route for displaying the result:

```
meme.find().sort(url).exec(function(err, result) { 
    //meme.find().sort({url}, function(err, result){

        if (err) throw err; 
        res.render('pages/index', {

            user: req.user, 
            pathi: result.map(i => i.memeid),
            path: result.map(u => u.url),
            caption: result.map(c => c.caption),
            tags: result.map(t => t.tags),  
            Title: 'Meme Search Engine'

        }); 

    });
})
```

Here is my EJS template for displaying the result:

```
 <% for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) { %>


      <a href="tags/<%= tags[i] %>"> <%= tags[i] %> </a> 


<%}%>
```

I hope am not missing anything.

How do I make my result separate instead of displaying with the comma?

Thanks!

Comment: the best thing I can suggest is to add the exact value of JSON.stringify(result.map(t => t.tags)) to the question, it may help. If I were in your place (happens every day) I would be stepping through this with a debugger to find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your question in Quora. Well, I would modify the memeSchema in this field:

```
tags: [String]
```

Let me know if that helps. If not, split tags[i] by ','

For example:

```
 <% for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) { 
       var tags_array = tags[i];
       tags_array = tags_array.split(',');
       for(var j = 0; j < tags_array.length; j++){%>


      <a href="tags/<%= tags_array[j] %>"> <%=  tags_array[j] %> </a> 

     <%}%> 
<%}%>
```

Comment: When I applied your solution, it's throwing 
`tags[i].split is not a function` error.  @AdolfoSolis

Comment: Indeed, my code is wrong. Modify: var tags_array = tags[i];
           tags_array = tags_array.split(',');

Comment: I've figured out the solution from your previous solution . Thanks so much.

Comment: but what was the problem? was it the data or the template?

Comment: The data. I appreciate your help.